# Problem installing R 4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (ARM architecture)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install R 4.2 in a GNU/Linux Machine with ARM architecture (Apple M1 Max).

After following the instructions given in https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

I got the following error message:

```
"r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.0-1.2004.0) but 3.6.3-2 is to be installed"
```

I've checked my /etc/apt/sources.list and I don't have duplicated entries for R, I only have:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
```

I also tried using the following line:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

but I still get the same error.

Any suggestion to be able to install R 4.2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Those CRAN instructions for Ubuntu are _not_ extensible to CPU platforms beyond x86_64.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk.I think I'll have to wait until the next stable release of Ubuntu to get an updated version of R. I would like to contribute but my knowledge is not enough to *extend* the instructions for Ubuntu beyond x86_64.